# Sendmail Error on OS X Mountain Lion

Tags: macos

I get an error when trying to run sendmail. I am on OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion.

```
sendmail: fatal: chdir /Library/Server/Mail/Data/spool: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Just execute in terminal

```
sudo mkdir -p /Library/Server/Mail/Data/spool
sudo /usr/sbin/postfix set-permissions
sudo /usr/sbin/postfix start
```

That did the trick for me.

Comment: Thanks tried that, mail not going out and getting the following error:    postdrop: warning: mail_queue_enter: create file maildrop/609676.26828: Permission denied

Comment: I had to do sudo /usr/sbin/postfix set-permissions      as well and now it works

Comment: Thanks a bunch, this worked like a charm even though it threw some odd errors and warnings out.

Comment: I followed > sudo mkdir... and it works. Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 23):

In order to get rid of all warnings I had to do the following:

```
sudo mkdir -p /Library/Server/Mail/Data/spool
sudo gzip /usr/share/man/man1/{postalias.1,postcat.1,postconf.1,postdrop.1,postfix.1,postkick.1,postlock.1,postlog.1,postmap.1,postmulti.1,postqueue.1,postsuper.1,sendmail.1}
sudo gzip /usr/share/man/man5/{access.5,aliases.5,bounce.5,canonical.5,cidr_table.5,generic.5,header_checks.5,ldap_table.5,master.5,mysql_table.5,nisplus_table.5,pcre_table.5,pgsql_table.5,postconf.5,postfix-wrapper.5,regexp_table.5,relocated.5,tcp_table.5,transport.5,virtual.5}
sudo gzip /usr/share/man/man8/{anvil.8,bounce.8,cleanup.8,discard.8,error.8,flush.8,local.8,master.8,oqmgr.8,pickup.8,pipe.8,proxymap.8,qmgr.8,qmqpd.8,scache.8,showq.8,smtp.8,smtpd.8,spawn.8,tlsmgr.8,trivial-rewrite.8,verify.8,virtual.8}
sudo /usr/sbin/postfix set-permissions
sudo chmod 700 /Library/Server/Mail/Data/mta
sudo /usr/sbin/postfix start
```

Comment: I don't think zipping the man pages is necessary.

Comment: Zipping the man pages is necessary to avoid this warning when running set-permissions: `chown: /usr/share/man/man1/postalias.1.gz: No such file or directory`

Comment: This worked like a charm, just pasted it all in and good go to.  Thanks @Jasper!

Answer (score 3):

The solution appears to also fix an error in 10.8 where the fax service has stopped sending emails after the 10.8 upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR**: Change the `queue_directory` variable in `/etc/postfix/main.cf` to `/var/spool/postfix`.

**Full answer:**

The `mkdir -p` [approach](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/57515/12625) likely works, but I suspect there's a simpler solution. Fair warning, I am new to Postfix, and this may all be incorrect.

It seems various editions of Mac OS X use one of two root directories for mail:

- `/var/spool/postfix`
- `/Library/Server/Mail`

These two seem to have been muddled over time. (Note `/var` is actually a symlink to `/private/var`, so you often see those used interchangeably.)

From what I can tell, `/Library/Server/Mail` is a directory that [Mac OS X Server](http://www.apple.com/osx/server/) uses for its Mail services, which depend on, but are not the same as, Postfix. `/var/spool/postfix`, on the other hand, is the [preferred directory (p. 14)](http://manuals.info.apple.com/MANUALS/1000/MA1179/en_US/MailServicesAdmin_v10.6.pdf)  for Postfix's internal operations.

There are two major configuration files which references these directories:

- `/etc/postfix/main.cf`
- `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.postfix.master.plist`

You're seeing the "No such file or directory error," I suspect, because the `queue_directory` variable in Postfix's `main.cf` refers to `/Library/Server/Mail/Data/spool`, which does not exist. On regular Mac OS X ([unlike Server](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS5175?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US)), the entire `/Library/Server` directory doesn't exist. Instead of creating it, try correcting the `queue_directory` variable to be `/var/spool/postfix`.

A second point of inconsistency is in the default settings for launchd, Mac OS X's daemon manager. It isn't necessary to run Postfix all of the time, as launchd can [watch a directory](http://paul.annesley.cc/2012/09/mac-os-x-launchd-is-cool/) for outgoing mail and only run Postfix when there's something to send. To make sure this will happen, the `QueueDirectories` key in `org.postfix.master.plist` needs to list the `maildrop` subdirectory of the directory in `main.cf`'s `queue_directory` variable. For example, I changed my `org.postfix.master.plist` file to include:

```
<key>QueueDirectories</key>
<array>
        <string>/var/spool/postfix/maildrop</string>
</array>
```

With these two directories consistent, Postfix should launch. You should be able to watch `/var/log/mail.log` while you run:

```
$ sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.postfix.master.plist
$ sudo launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.postfix.master.plist
$ sudo launchctl start org.postfix.master
```

The last of these commands [kick-starts](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/launchctl.1.html) Postfix, so you can watch `mail.log` for immediate debugging feedback, but again it isn't necessary to execute on a normal basis. Launchd will run Postfix as needed. (If you are certain you want Postfix running all the time, use the `KeepAlive` key detailed in the [`launchd.plist` man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/launchd.plist.5.html).)